# Getting the data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

In view page I've -

```
<button type="button" class="btn-highlight" data-next-popover-id="popover-2">Some Button</button>
```

In javascript I've -

```
target = $('#' + currentPopoverId.data('next-popover-id'));
target.popover('show');
```

In javascript I want to get the value `popover-2`. Using `target` Is there any way to get this? I've already tried with `target.text()`, `target.value()`; but not luck.

Comment: try: `$('#' + currentPopoverId.attr('data-next-popover-id'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`target = $('#' + currentPopoverId.attr('data-next-popover-id'));`

it's an attribute.. so name the attribute. It's not *actually* data.

Comment: thanks. But what I want is 'popover-2' if we do - `alert(target)` after applying your change we get [object object]. I actually want 'popover-2'

Comment: @Razib Then you need to explain how you are getting `currentPopoverId`, because it would seem that you aren't targeting the button properly to begin with. There's certainly no ID in that button. Using `target = $('.btn-highlight').attr('data-next-popover-id");` should work, but I don't know if you have other buttons with the same class.